# how to fix math random method group to float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

heres the error Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'float'

heres the code

```
public Transform[] Spawns;

Random.Range(1, Spawns.GetLength);
```

Comment: `Spawns.GetLength` -> `Spawns.GetLength()` (or just `Spawns.Length`)

Comment: oh ok i will try that

Comment: It worked i used Spawns.Length

Answer (score 1):

`Array.GetLength` is the name of [a *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength), meaning you need to supply a list of arguments enclosed in `()` to invoke it:

```
Random.Range(1, Spawns.GetLength(0));
```

That being said, the more idiomatic solution for assessing the length of a 1-deminsional array in C# would be to just use [the `Length` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length):

```
Random.Range(1, Spawns.Length);
```